# Getting the sum of 2 different indices from 2 separate arrays

Tags: java, arrays, abstract

Very new to Java, so please bear with me here. I have to write a program based on the resident status of a student to determine the total cost for the term.  I must use Abstract methods (separate class), and then create classes based on Tuition for Full time and Part Time. The full and part-time classes must use arrays.  I probably wrote the array list wrong, but this is what I have so far, and I need to create an object "county" so I can calculate the cost for the student who resides in the county.

**How do I call the tuition and capital fee to add them together for the index C only?** Or, would it be easier if I write an array for just county with the tuition and capital fee then sum those together, then add that total to the other costs listed?  Also, when I try to create the object under county, it comes up with an error.  I will be using Radio Buttons to determine what the resident status of the student is, (not sure if that changes things for my calculations). Any help is appreciated.

The abstract class:

```
package collegecost1;

public abstract class collegeAbMain {
    public abstract double tuition();
    public abstract double capitalFee();
    public abstract double accidentIns();
    public abstract double collegeFee();

    //public abstract double county();
    //public abstract double outCounty();
    //public abstract double outState();

}
```

fullTime class:

```
 package collegecost1;

 public class fullTime extends collegeAbMain {
     double  C;
     double OC;
     double OS;
     double Ins;
     double fee;
     double total;


     @Override
     public double tuition() {
         double resident = 3;
         double [] tuition = new double [(int) resident];

         // I have to use the variables C, OC, and OS
         tuition[0] = C;
         C = 1571.25;

         tuition[1] = OC;
         OC = 3142.50;

         tuition[2] = OS;
         OS = 4713.75;
         return resident;
     }

     @Override
     public double capitalFee() {
         double resident = 3;
         double[] capitalFee = new double [(int) resident];

         capitalFee[0] = C;
         C = 0.00;

         capitalFee[1] = OC;
         OC = 78.00;

         capitalFee[2] = OS;
         OS = 78.00;

         return resident ;
     }

     @Override
     public double accidentIns() {
        Ins = 0.00;
        return Ins;
    }

    @Override
    public double collegeFee() {
        fee = 50.40;
        return fee;
    }

    public double county() {
     county total = new county()
    //ERROR (wants me to create class or interface for the 1st word county
    // have written objects the exact same way in other programs and never
    // had an issue. 
        {   
          //NOT THE ACTUAL CODE

                  //total = (index[0] from resident tution +
          //index [0] from resident caplitalFee)
                  //+ (Ins) + (fee);

              return total();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This code majorly confuses me. You make lots of arrays and then just throw them away.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I probably wrote the arrays wrong.  I am confused how to do this, and then call them to do what I want, which is why I wrote what I need to do with them  as a // comment in the code.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm guessing you don't need any arrays; just do some calculations to get your tuition etc.

Comment: I originally had that, but my teacher added she wanted things done in abstract and with arrays.  If I can't figure it out, I will rewrite the one I had and just use that one and lose some points. Thank you.

Comment: Tell us exactly what your assignment says. If you are not sure then ask your instructor. Then read & act on [mcve]. If edits to your question would invalidate any reasonable answer(s) already posted, ask a new question.

Comment: Probably she wants you to use an `abstract class` because both classes (FullTime and PartTime) are very similar. So you would have to put the duplicate methods (tuition and so on) into the abstract class because it can have method implementations. You would then simply call them in your other classes `county` methods, as long as they extend the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need arrays for this job. Further in your code you always return `resident` instead of the array. Try something like this:

```
public double tuition(String s) {

    double acc = 0;

    if (s.equals("C")) {
        acc = 1571.25;
    } else if (s.equals("OC")) {
        acc = 3142.50;
    } else if (s.equals("OS")) {
        acc = 4713.75;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter C, OC or OS!");
    }
    return acc;

}

public double capitalFee(String s) {

    double acc = 0;

    if (s.equals("C")) {
        acc = 0.00;
    } else if (s.equals("OC") || s.equals("OS")) {
        acc = 78.00;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter C, OC or OS!");
    }
    return acc;

}

public double accidentIns() {
    double ins = 0.00;
    return ins;
}

public double collegeFee() {
    double fee = 50.40;
    return fee;
}

public double county(String a, String b) {
    return tuition(a) + capitalFee(b) + accidentIns() + collegeFee();

}
```

And you can't do `county total = new county()`. You are trying to create an object of a method. You will need a `class` called `County` with a constructor to do this.

Here an example with arrays:

```
public double[] tuition() {

    double[] tuition = new double[3];

    double C = 1571.25;
    tuition[0] = C;

    double OC = 3142.50;
    tuition[1] = OC;

    double OS = 4713.75;
    tuition[2] = OS;

    return tuition;

}

public double[] capitalFee() {

    double[] capitalFee = new double[3];

    double C = 0.00;
    capitalFee[0] = C;

    double OC = 78.00;
    capitalFee[1] = OC;

    double OS = 78.00;
    capitalFee[2] = OS;

    return capitalFee;
}

public double accidentIns() {
    double ins = 0.00;
    return ins;
}

public double collegeFee() {
    double fee = 50.40;
    return fee;
}

public double county(String s) {
    double result = 0;
    double[] tuition = tuition();
    double[] capitalFee = capitalFee();
    if (s.equals("C")) {
        result = tuition[0] + capitalFee[0] + accidentIns() + collegeFee();
    } else if (s.equals("OC")) {
        result = tuition[1] + capitalFee[1] + accidentIns() + collegeFee();
    } else if (s.equals("OS")) {
        result = tuition[2] + capitalFee[2] + accidentIns() + collegeFee();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter C, OC or OS!");
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I might have figure out how to do the Array list, I will make one for County, so I can sum up the array, and so forth for the other 2 resident statuses.  I will report back this weekend if I get it all together and it works.

Answer (score 0):

> The full and part time classes must use Array's

> I will be using Radio Buttons to determine what the resident status of the student is

You have not explained enough for us to know how your methods should act or what it can mean that "classes must use arrays". But since you are going to input "to determine what the resident status of the student is", presumably you must tell some object what county you are interested in so that it can give the right info. So the object state involves info *for each county*. That suggests arrays to represent the object state. Also there must be some way to input that information. (Although not necessarily through an interface/object accessible to all users of the four methods you list & a method giving what county they are to report about.) It seems that you do not have a clear idea of what you are supposed to do. So find out.

Comment: I have 5 programs that I am writing for this project.  I did not upload the other classes as I do not need help with those.  Abstract class to hold the Tuition, CaptialFee, CollegeFee, and AccidentIns which I posted.  Full time class to hold the Array values of full time costs, Part Time class to hold Array values of part time costs.  GUI class for student to input information, radio buttons to determine resident status, then that will determine which calculation is to be called to determine total cost for the term.

Comment: All I have seen so far, in my book and online, is adding all the elements of 1 array, I have not been able to find how to write the code and add the elements of 2 separate index of 2 separate arrays.  I wrote that as a comment in my code.  array tuition with indices : county, out of county, out of state with their values.  array capital fee with indices: county, out of county, and out of state, with their values.  Then add the tuition index county to the capital fee index county.  The action listener is in a separate class, as the full and part time are only for the values and calculations.

Comment: That does not address the problems with your question. If you have encapsulated your arrays in another class, these methods should be accessing it, and why mention arrays in your question? What indeed is your question? According to your comment here, it involves using other classes you don't even mention in it and doesn't involve arrays, and your compilation error is yet another question. Per my comment on your question, please edit your question to clarify what the specification is and what objects are available for implementing it. (Unless it invalidates answers based on how it is now.)

Comment: Your use of local arrays indexed by 1-3 for C, OC & OS is strange & pointless and seems extremely unlikely to be what an assignment would want you to do. But if it is correct, what are you asking about? Your current wording does not make that clear. You must make a per-county data object with a method inputting the county available to this code. And why are you mixing this with the compilation error? Re that error, read about name scoping: You are trying to have a method with the the same name as a class it uses and you haven't made a defintion of that class (county) available. Also **MCVE**.